# How to export multiple queries as individual files into the same directory?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using `VBA` in `Access 2010`, I need to export multiple queries into individual respective files, using the same folder.

Example:

```
QueryA into myFolder\myfileA.txt

QueryB into myFolder\myfileB.txt

QueryC into myFolder\myfileC.txt
```

This is my code, and I am wondering if there is a way to do this using a single function.

```
Function ExportA()
  DoCmd.TransferText transfertype:=acExportDelim, _
   tablename:="QueryA", _
   FileName:="MyFolder\MyFileA.txt", _
   hasfieldnames:=True
End Function

Function ExportB()
  DoCmd.TransferText transfertype:=acExportDelim, _
   tablename:="QueryB", _
   FileName:="MyFolder\MyFileB.txt", _
   hasfieldnames:=True
End Function

Public Sub test()
Call ExportA
Call ExportB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the table name as a parameter:

```
function exportObject(objectName as string) as boolean
on error goto oops
    dim ans as boolean
    ans = false

    DoCmd.Transfertext transferType := acExportDelim, _
        tableName := objectName, _
        fileName := "MyFolder\" & objectName & ".txt", _
        hasFieldNames := True
    ans = true
    ' Show a confirmation message
    MsgBox "'" & objectName &"' has been exported"

exitExportObject:
    exportObject = ans
    exit function

oops:
    ans = false ' Something went wrong
    ' Add some error handling code here, for example, show a message:
    MsgBox "ERROR: Couldn't export '" & objectName &"'"
    goto exitExportObject
end function
```

Then create another procedure to call the function multiple times

```
public function exportMyObjects()
    exportObject "QueryA"
    exportObject "QueryB"
    exportObject "QueryC"
end function
```

Comment: I know this is a different question but is there a way to get a Message Window when the Query has completed?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Check the edit. You can call `MsgBox` to show a message any time you want.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all you need to do it substitute the function call for the actual code. It would look like this.

```
 Public Sub exportTest()
     DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QueryA", "C:/MyFolder/MyFileA.txt", True
     DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QueryB", "C:/MyFolder/MyFileB.txt", True
     DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QueryC", "C:/MyFolder/MyFileC.txt", True
 Exit Sub
```